# "Chromium didn't shut down correctly" message after almost every snap update since Ubuntu 19.10, 20.04

Tags: updates, 20.04, chromium, snap

Almost every time my Chromium browser on Ubuntu 20.04 gets an update, next time I start Chromium I will get this annoying message "Chromium didn't shut down correctly" and the option to restore tabs. Also, the Chromium icon wich I have locked to the Unity launcher is removed so I have to lock it again.

I presume this has to do with the way the updates are installed as snaps and without asking me to close Chromium before. So usually it seems to happen that the updates are installed while Chromium is running, causing it to not being able to close properly, thus the error message at next start after update.

The updates are installed via snapcraft.io it says in Gnome Software info and not through repositories. Can I change to the traditional repository installation for Chromium? That way, I would see the updates coming and simply close Chromium before starting a Chromium update.

Comment: Chromium is no longer packaged as a deb - the workload of re-packaging every Chromium release for every supported release of Ubuntu was simply too onerous. Please file a bug report for the snap at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap -- the snap packages want to know about papercuts exactly like these! You can find the bug contact for any snap using `snap info <snap_name>`